# How to get predicted value in Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, supervised-learning

I am trying build predictive system into a MERN app. I am new to Tensorflow and just followed [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#6) tutorial which gets relation between Horsepower and Miles per gallon.

```
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#6
```

I've not understood how to utilize this to get a predicted value. How do I enter a horsepower in input field and get predicted MPG.

```
const xs = tf.linspace(0, 1, 100);      
  const preds = model.predict(xs.reshape([100, 1]));
```

The above line is used to plot range of horsepower from low to high I guess. But how do I get a predicted value for entered value?

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Given the model, the features are a 2d dimensional data.

If you have an input field value, you can find its prediction by using

```
const tensor = model.predict(tf.tensor([valueOfInput], [1, 1]))
// Get the value
const value = tensor.dataSync()[0]
```

Comment: I added above line and console logged it. following is the response - {"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[1,1],"dtype":"float32","size":1,"strides":[1],"dataId":{},"id":10892,"rankType":"2"}. Is this the way it should be. I was expecting a single value for the input

Comment: const price = model.predict(tf.tensor([96087], [1, 1]));

Comment: If you want to get the value, you can use `datasync()` or `data()`. You can see my edited answer.