# How to access predicted values from SciKit.js SVM LinearSVC model in TensorFlow.js?

Tags: javascript, scikit-learn, svm, tensorflow.js, scikit.js

I'm trying to perform a classification with a SVM model. I'm using SciKit.js cause, according to the datasheet, it's the same as its Python version, and I know it a little.
First, as a learning exercice, I want a model able to predict in which quart of a square a point is (bottom-left, bottom-right, top-left, top-right).

Here is my code :

```js
// Importing libs, following datasheet
import * as tf from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@tensorflow/tfjs'
// import {setBackend, trainTestSplit} from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/scikitjs'
import * as sk from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/scikitjs'
sk.setBackend(tf)

// function creating dataset
function genererVecteur() {
    let datas_gen = {};
    let valeurs = [];
    let labels = [];
    let x, y;
    let position;
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        x = Math.random();
        y = Math.random();
        position = y < 0.5 ? 'bas ' : `haut `;
        position += x < 0.5 ? 'gauche' : 'droite';
        valeurs.push(([x, y]));
        labels.push(position);
    }
    datas_gen.datas = valeurs;
    datas_gen.labels = labels;
    return datas_gen;
}

// Normalizing datas 
const scaler = new sk.StandardScaler();
scaler.fit(X_train);
let X_train_std = scaler.transform(X_train);
let X_test_std = scaler.transform(X_test);

// Normalizing labels, as the SVC training function accept only numbers as "targets", not strings
const encodeur = new encodeurSurN();
encodeur.fit(Y_train);
let Y_train_std = encodeur.encode(Y_train);
let Y_test_std = encodeur.encode(Y_test);

async function goIA(){
    // creating model
    let svc = new sk.LinearSVC();
    // training model
    await svc.fit(X_train_std, Y_train_std);
    console.log("modèle entraîné");
    //Test
    let Y_predict = svc.predict(X_test_std);
    console.log("prédictions faites");
    //Evaluation
    console.log(Y_predict);
    // console.log(Y_predict.item()); // not a function
    // console.log(Y_predict[0]); // undefined
}
goIA();
```

`svc.fit` method is waiting for 2 arguments : a samples array, and a targets array. But the target array can't contain strings, so I created a class "convert" my labels to ints. (instead of just changing my dataset, as I want to easily read predicted positions, so I've an `encode` and a `decode` method.)
Here is my `encodeurSurN` class, I wrote it to use it the same way as the scaler for datas :

```js
class encodeurSurN{
    constructor(){
    }
    fit(vecteur){
        this.valeursUniques = Array.from(new Set(vecteur));
    }
    encode(vecteur){
        let vecteur_codes = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < vecteur.length; i++){
            vecteur_codes.push(this.valeursUniques.indexOf(vecteur[i]));
        }
        return vecteur_codes;
    }
    decode(vecteur){
        let vecteur_valeurs = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < vecteur.length; i++){
            vecteur_valeurs.push(this.valeursUniques[vecteur[i]]);
        }
        return vecteur_valeurs;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to reed what is in `Y_predict`, so I can have an idea of the code to write to compare it to `Y_test` and check is my model is good enough, but the `console.log(Y_predict);` line is just returning me the Tensor as :

```
Tensor {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(1), dtype: 'float32', size: 30, …}
dataId:{id: 94413}
dtype:"float32"
id:76638
isDisposedInternal:false
kept:false
rankType:"1"
shape:[30]
size:30
strides:[]
isDisposed:(...)
rank:(...)
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

But I don't have any Idea of what it is, as I don't know TensorFlow, and google don't seems to have an easy way to see my labels in this.

So I tried to use `console.log(Y_predict.item());` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74917728/how-to-access-the-tensor-value), even if it's about Pytorch... maybe there is common key words ? (topic suggested as an answer to my title when i was writing my own topic). but I had the error "Not a function".
I also tried to use [dataSync() and data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115214/how-to-get-predicted-value-in-tensorflow-js) and it's... working ? well I've an array full of `1`. So the prediction is just false. Is it the good way to access the predictions in a tensor ? Or maybe it's the good way and there are errors in my script ?

P.S. : If you want to try the code, it can be long to run the `await svc.fit(X_train_std, Y_train_std);` instruction.
It seems it's a young library, here is a link to datasheet : [quick start](https://scikitjs.org/docs/tutorial/)